# Filtering a table. Show content if one of the rules apply

Tags: jquery, button, filter

I have a table where I can filter if a certain person is an illustrator or writer.

```
<table>
  <tr class="writer">
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>Jan 01, 1980</td>
    <td>jondoe@domain.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="writer illustrator">
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
    <td>Sept 01, 1980</td>
    <td>janedoe@domain.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="illustrator">
    <td>Mel Smith</td>
    <td>Aug 01, 1980</td>
    <td>meeeeel@domain.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="writer">
    <td>Harry Smith</td>
    <td>Dec 01, 1980</td>
    <td>hsmith@domain.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="writer">writer</button>
<button id="illustrator">illustrator</button>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

and this is the jquery

```
jQuery(function () {
$('#illustrator').click(function () {
    $('table tr.writer').hide();
    $('table tr.illustrator').show();
})
$('#writer').click(function () {
    $('table tr.writer').show();
    $('table tr.illustrator').hide();
})
$('#reset').click(function () {
    $('table tr').show();
})
})
```

My problem right now is if the table row has the same class, this certain row doesnt appear. Like for this example Jane Doe doesnt appear when I click writer. How do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just change the order of hide and show

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#illustrator').click(function () {
        $('table tr.writer').hide();
        $('table tr.illustrator').show();
    })
    $('#writer').click(function () {
        $('table tr.illustrator').hide();
        $('table tr.writer').show();
    })
    $('#reset').click(function () {
        $('table tr').show();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hUZF3/)

---

If you want to spice it a little bit, you can ignore those entries by using :not-selector like

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#illustrator').click(function () {
        $('table tr:not(.illustrator)').hide();
        $('table tr.illustrator').show();
    })
    $('#writer').click(function () {
        $('table tr:not(.writer)').hide();
        $('table tr.writer').show();
    })
    $('#reset').click(function () {
        $('table tr').show();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hUZF3/3/)

---

Another variant to support multiple types is to have a single handler for the buttons and specify the target type in them like

```
<button class="trigger" data-target="writer">writer</button>
<button class="trigger" data-target="illustrator">illustrator</button>
<button class="trigger">reset</button>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.trigger').click(function () {
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        if (target) {
            $('table tr:not(.' + target + ')').hide();
            $('table tr.' + target).show();
        } else {
            $('table tr').show();
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hUZF3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

just try below code..You need to change the ordering in coding as shown below.

```
 $('#writer').click(function () {
        $('table tr.illustrator').hide();
        $('table tr.writer').show();
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/avmCX/23/

Answer (score 0):

you must check the element has not your class

```
jQuery(function () {
            $('#illustrator').click(function () {
                $('table tr.writer:not(.illustrator)').hide();
                $('table tr.illustrator').show();
            })
            $('#writer').click(function () {
                $('table tr.writer').show();
                $('table tr.illustrator:not(.writer)').hide();
            })
            $('#reset').click(function () {
                $('table tr').show();
            })
        })
```